# How to create a new "time difference" column from start and finish time columns in an R table

Tags: r, time

I have been given a table of data to analyse.
I have a column with start times and a column with finish times given in 3 or 4 digits, example: 3:40pm is 1540, 7:25am is 725.

How can I obtain a new column in my table with the difference of these times, given in minutes?
There are over 2000 entries.

Thanks for any help.

```
structure(list(schedtime = c(1455L, 1640L, 1245L, 1715L, 1039L, 
840L), deptime = c(1455L, 1640L, 1245L, 1709L, 1035L, 839L), 
distance = c(184L, 213L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 228L), flightnumber = 
c(5935L, 
6155L, 7208L, 7215L, 7792L, 7800L), weather = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), dayweek = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), daymonth = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is an example of the dataset (Im unsure are to why there are L's after each number, these are not shown in the table). I want, in minutes, deptime (finish) - schedtime (start).

Given the new column, there are 2 values with a schedtime before midnight and a deptime after midnight, for example schedtime 2120 and deptime 0010. The answer to this is given as -1270, considering it to be an extremely early departure. How could I change this to be calculated as +170, a late departure?

Comment: Please update your question with sample data using `dput`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efficient way for larger dataset-

```
data.table::setDT(dt)[,time_diff:=minutes(deptime-schedtime)]

> dt
   schedtime deptime distance flightnumber weather dayweek daymonth time_diff
1:      1455    1455      184         5935       0       4        1        0S
2:      1640    1640      213         6155       0       4        1        0S
3:      1245    1245      229         7208       0       4        1        0S
4:      1715    1709      229         7215       0       4        1    -6M 0S
5:      1039    1035      229         7792       0       4        1    -4M 0S
6:       840     839      228         7800       0       4        1    -1M 0S
```

**EDIT-** (To handle cases like 1730 - 1600 = 130 mins ( Actually, it is 90 mins).

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
setDT(dt)
dt[,schedtime:=str_pad(schedtime, 4, pad = "0")]
dt[,deptime:=str_pad(deptime, 4, pad = "0")]

dt[,time_diff:=difftime(as.ITime(strptime(x = schedtime, format = "%H%M")),as.ITime(strptime(x = deptime, format = "%H%M")),units = "mins")]


> dt
   schedtime deptime distance flightnumber weather dayweek daymonth time_diff
1:      1455    1455      184         5935       0       4        1    0 mins
2:      1640    1640      213         6155       0       4        1    0 mins
3:      1245    1245      229         7208       0       4        1    0 mins
4:      1715    1709      229         7215       0       4        1    6 mins
5:      1039    1035      229         7792       0       4        1    4 mins
6:      1730    1600      228         7800       0       4        1   90 mins
```

Comment: Error in data.table::setDT(dt) : 
  Can not convert 'dt' to data.table by reference because binding is locked. It is very likely that 'dt' resides within a package (or an environment) that is locked to prevent modifying its variable bindings. Try copying the object to your current environment, ex: var <- copy(var) and then using setDT again. I get this error, do you know how to fix it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: oh you can remove dt and restart R session or you can copy `dt` to new object like `dt_copy <- copy(dt) ` and then `setDT(dt_copy)`

Comment: Which package do I need to download for the copy function?

Comment: its a function from `data.table` package

Comment: did u install `data.table` package?

Comment: I have this package but get error: could not find function "copy"

Comment: that's not possible, which version of `data.table` package are you using? Also, did you do `library(data.table)`

Comment: I didn't do library(data.table), the copy function works now. Sorry I'm very new to R. I now get the error: Error in data.table::setDT(dt_copy) : 
  Argument 'x' to 'setDT' should be a 'list', 'data.frame' or 'data.table'

Comment: did you create `dt_copy` from `dt`?

Comment: I did. This gives incorrect answers, for example 1730 - 1600 = 130 minutes, however this is actually 90 minutes.

Comment: Added new answer, please check.

Comment: This works great, thank you. How would you handle a value from 2120 to 0010? Currently the code considers this to be a negative (early) delay -1270 but I would like it to be 170. I understand this is an issue of not having the dates. There are few of these issues, is there a way I could change them each manually?

Answer (score 0):

```
dat <- data.frame(c(1540,1820,1330,545,100),c(1850,2150,2325,1330,101))
60*(floor(dat[,2]/100) - floor(dat[,1]/100)) - dat[,1] %% 100 + dat[,2] %% 100
```

Taking the floor of the the hundreds gives the hours. Taking the difference and multiplying by 60 gives the minutes from the difference of the hours. Then you can subtract the original minutes and add the final minutes to get total minutes passed.

Comment: Would there be a way to calculate is down the columns and create a new column with the answers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use library lubridate to find the difference in minutes . Hope this helps. lubridate provides very good functionality for time related data.

```
library(lubridate)
df$deptime_new <- minutes(df$deptime-df$schedtime)
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(schedtime = c(1455L, 1640L, 1245L, 1715L, 1039L, 
                                   840L), deptime = c(1455L, 1640L, 1245L, 1709L, 1035L, 839L), 
                     distance = c(184L, 213L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 228L), flightnumber = 
                       c(5935L, 
                         6155L, 7208L, 7215L, 7792L, 7800L), weather = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                         0L, 0L, 0L), dayweek = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), daymonth = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: With this I get the error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: This gives incorrect answers, for example 1730 - 1600 = 130 minutes, however this is actually 90 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same query, Is there a way to calculate the time difference of times in a column and display the answers in a new column in minutes

Comment: Please use the comment section as this is not an answer.